# Django deployment error "usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE] gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: "

Tags: django, deployment, gunicorn, wsgi

I am trying to deploy a Django app on a Linux virtual machine created on Google Computing Engine (GCE). My domain name works fine but the wsgi server does not run because of the error in the title.
`supervisor.log` looks like tis.

```
.
.
.
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments:
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments:
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments:
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments:
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments:
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments:
```

I am having a hard time troubleshooting because it does not tell me where to look into.

The error seems to occur when I run `gunicorn_start`  via commands such as `sudo supervisorvtl restart tutorial` or `chmod +x .../venv/bin/gunicorn_start` because I can run the contents of the file directly via my terminal.

This is how my file tree looks like:

```
/webapp/user
        |--- req.txt
        |--- venv
        |--- tutorial
            |-- req.txt
            |--manage.py
            |--tutorial
            .
            .
            .
                |--wsgi.py
                |--settings.py
                .
                .
                .
```

I thought that the cause of this error is in the contents of the `gunicorn_start` file. So I ran the shell scripts in the file directly in the VM's terminal and the wsgi server seems to be running fine. Here's the  result.

```
[13634] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  config: ./gunicorn.conf.py
  wsgi_app: None
  bind: ['unix:/home/user/webapp/user/venv/run/gunicorn.sock']
  backlog: 2048
  workers: 3
  worker_class: sync
  threads: 1
  worker_connections: 1000
  max_requests: 0
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  timeout: 120
  graceful_timeout: 30
  keepalive: 2
  limit_request_line: 4094
  limit_request_fields: 100
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  reload: False
  reload_engine: auto
  reload_extra_files: []
  spew: False
  check_config: False
  print_config: False
  preload_app: False
  sendfile: None
  reuse_port: False
  chdir: /home/user/webapp/user/tutorial
  daemon: False
  raw_env: []
  pidfile: None
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  user: 1000
  group: 1001
  umask: 0
  initgroups: False
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  accesslog: None
  disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  errorlog: -
  loglevel: debug
  capture_output: False
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  logconfig: None
  logconfig_dict: {}
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog: False
  syslog_prefix: None
  syslog_facility: user
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  statsd_host: None
  dogstatsd_tags:
  statsd_prefix:
  proc_name: tutorial
  default_proc_name: tutorial.wsgi:application
  pythonpath: None
  paste: None
  on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7fc0ec8c4b80>
  on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7fc0ec8c4ca0>
  when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7fc0ec8c4dc0>
  pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7fc0ec8c4ee0>
  post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7fc0ec8d9040>
  post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7fc0ec8d9160>
  worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7fc0ec8d9280>
  worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7fc0ec8d93a0>
  pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7fc0ec8d94c0>
  pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7fc0ec8d95e0>
  post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7fc0ec8d9670>
  child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7fc0ec8d9790>
  worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7fc0ec8d98b0>
  nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7fc0ec8d99d0>
  on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7fc0ec8d9af0>
  proxy_protocol: False
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  keyfile: None
  certfile: None
  ssl_version: 2
  cert_reqs: 0
  ca_certs: None
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  ciphers: None
  raw_paste_global_conf: []
  strip_header_spaces: False
[2022-05-18 00:55:48 +0000] [13634] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-05-18 00:55:48 +0000] [13634] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2022-05-18 00:55:48 +0000] [13634] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/user/webapp/user/venv/run/gunicorn.sock (13634)
[2022-05-18 00:55:48 +0000] [13634] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-05-18 00:55:48 +0000] [15864] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15864
[2022-05-18 00:55:48 +0000] [15865] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15865
[2022-05-18 00:55:48 +0000] [15866] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15866
[2022-05-18 00:55:48 +0000] [13634] [DEBUG] 3 workers
```

My `gunicorn_start` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
NAME='tutorial'
DJANGODIR=/home/user/webapp/user/tutorial
SOCKFILE=/home/user/webapp/user/venv/run/gunicorn.sock
USER=user
GROUP=user
NUM_WORKERS=3
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=tutorial.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=tutorial.wsgi
TIMEOUT=120

cd $DJANGODIR
. ../venv/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec ../venv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
--chdir /home/user/webapp/yoshi/tutorial \
--name $NAME \
--workers $NUM_WORKERS \
--timeout $TIMEOUT \
--user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
--bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
--log-level=debug \
--log-file=-
```

Here's how `.conf` looks like:

```
[program:tutorial]

command = /home/user/webapp/user/venv/bin/gunicorn_start
user = user
stdout_logfile = /home/user/webapp/user/venv/logs/supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

This is how `~/webapp/user/req.txt` looks like:

```
asgiref==3.5.2
cachetools==5.1.0
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
Django==4.0.4
google-api-core==2.7.3
google-auth==2.6.6
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.10.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.56.1
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.4
grpcio==1.46.1
grpcio-status==1.46.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.3
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysqlclient==2.1.0
proto-plus==1.20.3
protobuf==3.20.1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
PyMySQL==1.0.2
requests==2.27.1
rsa==4.8
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.26.9
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have solved your problem.

For me the spaces (' ') between the parameters in `--access_logformat` were broken, it doesn't make sense, but to fix it I did:

```
--access-logformat %(h)s%(l)s%(u)s%(t)s"%(r)s"%(s)s%(b)s"%(f)s""%(a)s"%(T)s%(p)s
```